# Adding list object to class member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, smtp

I have an object that I am trying to add items to. In other examples with more complex classes i used ObservableCollections, but this was pretty simple (I thought). I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I attempt to add to the SendToList object, the last line. What am I doing wrong? Thanx in advance.

My model:

```
    public class MailModels
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string ToMain { get; set; }
    public string ToCC { get; set; }
    public string ToBCC { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<MailGetter> SendToList { get; set; }
    public List<MailGetter> SendToCCList { get; set; }
    public List<MailGetter> SendToBCCList { get; set; }
}

public class MailGetter
{
    public string MailName { get; set; }
    public string MailEmailAddy { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
        MailModels mm = new MailModels();
        // going to need a foreach loop here for multiple additions
        MailGetter mg = new MailGetter()
        {
            MailName = "myName",
            MailEmailAddy = "myname@myserver.com"            
        };

        mm.Subject = "test email";
        mm.Body = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        mm.SendToList.Add(mg);
```

Comment: where are you creating an new Instance of `public List<MailGetter> SendToList { get; set; }`
`mm.SendToList = new List<MailGetter>();` should fix it could see that instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not instantiated the List, Instantiate it before adding item in it:

```
mm.SendToList = new List<MailGetter>();
mm.SendToList.Add(mg);
```

or you can Instantiate them in Model's constructor:

```
 public class MailModels
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string ToMain { get; set; }
    public string ToCC { get; set; }
    public string ToBCC { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<MailGetter> SendToList { get; set; }
    public List<MailGetter> SendToCCList { get; set; }
    public List<MailGetter> SendToBCCList { get; set; }

    public MailModels()
    {
       this.SendToList  = new List<MailGetter>();
       this.SendToCCList = new new List<MailGetter>();
       this.SendToBCCList = new new List<MailGetter>();
    } 
}
```

and then you will not need to instantiate them again, as they are instantiated at Model's object creation time:

```
MailModels mm = new MailModels();
mm.SendToList.Add(mg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list is `null` at this point. You should initialize this before adding new items:

```
mm.SendToList = new List<MailGetter>();
mm.SendToList.Add(mg);
```

Or even better, you make the setter of the list private and initialize the list in the constructor of `MailModels`:

```
public class MailModels
{
    public MailModels()
    {
      this.SendToList = new List<MailGetter>();
    }

    ...
    public List<MailGetter> SendToList { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

This you can do for all your lists in the class. Then you don't need to initialize the list before accessing it. And you can be sure that the list is not `null`, because it can't be set to `null`from outside the class (because of the private setter).